# New way to solve Quadratic Equations?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

A couple months ago, I was challenged to discover a new way to solve quadratic equations with one rule: I must think of it myself. At first I was hopeless, trying various sorts of random things, but I finally found one way. My way is somewhat limited (extremely disappointing), however, but it still works in most cases. You must only know two things about the quadratic equation:

1. The leading coefficient of x^2 is 1
2. The difference of the two possible values of x

For example, you have a randomly-picked polynomial with the requirements stated above:

```
x^2+5x+6=0
Difference:1
```

Psst! The answer is:

```
x={-3,-2}
```

Which is derived from:

```
(x+3)(x+2)=0
```

Obviously, this can be solved in the matter of a second by simple factoring, but there is another way:

```
let y = greater value of x (-2)
let z = lesser value of x (-3)
```

Now, you have two new variables, y and z, but how do you use them? Make new equations!

```
y^2+5y+6=0
z^2+5z+6=0
```

Somehow, I pulled two magic equations out of thin air:

```
y^2-(difference*y)=coefficient c
z^2+(difference*z)=coefficient c
```

So, for our current example, the two equations would look like this:

```
y^2-(1)y=6
z^2+(1)z=6
```

Yay! Now we have a system of equations with like variables! The rest can be solved with simple linear combination.

```
y^2-1y=6 and y^2+5y+6=0 (y^2+5y=-6)
```

Adding the two equations gives:

```
2y^2+4y=0
```

Divide the whole equation by 2:

```
y^2+2y=0
```

Subtract 2y from both sides of the equation:

```
y^2=-2y
```

Divide both sides by y:

```
y=-2
```

Yay! That is the correct answer from above! Now, let's start the same super long process for z(I totally don't want to do this)!

The two equations for z again so you don't have to look up there again(I know, I'm a nice person):

```
z^2+1z=6 and z^2+5z+6 (z^2+5z=-6)
```

Adding the two equations together gives:

```
2z^2+6z=0
```

Divide the whole equation by 2 gives:

```
z^2+3z=0
```

Subtracting 3z from both sides of the equation gives:

```
z^2=-3z
```

Dividing both sides of the equation by z gives:

```
z=-3
```

Yay! The other solution for x! Now we have the same solution set as we had by factoring:

```
x={-3,-2}
```

Phew! Now that my past hour has been used writing this post, I am so tired! You guys are probably really tired too from reading a post from a crazy middle-schooler! Can you please try to help me expand my idea? 
Help will include:

```
1. Constructive Criticism
2. Deriving a Formula to Speed up this process
3. Find more ways to use this in quadratic equation solving
```

Thanks so much!

P.S. I didn't actually have to write out every step. I just wrote it for clarification for the readers.

Comment: Divide both sides by $y$? (Or by $z$ later on) You cannot do that! $y=0$ is a solution to that particular equation. I think I will stick with the Method of Completing the Square as the general approach for solving quadratic equations...

Comment: @imranfat
I know I am degrading the degree of the equation, but y=0 isn't a solution to the original equation. I guess I can write y does not equal to 0, but I didn't think it was quite necessary. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It seems like this method is just so much longer than the methods already out there...That said, if you are a middle schooler, then certainly the interest you show in math is noteworthy...

Comment: I am a middle schooler, taking  basically all highschool courses and several AP's. I really love math, but I am still boggled by how to derive a formula to speed up the process. One strong point that this method has is its simple algebraic steps. It will allow those that are not as good at using mental math still be able to solve quadratics.

Comment: If you know the difference $D= x_1-x_2$ between the two solutions of a quadratic $x^2 + bx + c = 0$ then you can more easily derive the solutions as $x_1 = \frac{D - b}{2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{-D-b}{2}$. This comes from expanding the right hand side of $x^2 + bx + c = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ and comparing to get $b=-x_1-x_2$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks so much! If you have ideas about my idea, fell free to post it as an answer! :P

Comment: By the way, there's another way. Hint: Let the quadratic be $(x+s)(x+t)$, so that the roots are $-s$ and $-t$. Now, expanding, we have $x^2+(s+t)x+(st)$. Thus, just by looking at the coefficients of the quadratic, we know $s+t$ and $st$. Define $A=s+t$ and $B=st$, so that the quadratic is $x^2+Ax+B$. Note three things: (1) $s+t$ and $st$ don't change when we switch $s$ and $t$. (2) $(s-t)^2$ doesn't change when we switch $s$ and $t$. Therefore: (3) Hopefully, we should be able to write $(s-t)^2$ in terms of the coefficients $A=s+t$ and $B=st$. I'll let you continue this by yourself.

Comment: (Remember that $(s-t)^2=(t-s)^2$. For example, $(3-5)^2=(-2)^2=4$ and $(5-3)^2=(2)^2=4$.)

Comment: yours is not quite random, here is my random, work it out with your method if you could: $x^2+4x+6=0$, Difference: $1$. Or try $x^2+7x+6=0$, Difference: $1$. I assure you they look completely random to me :)

Comment: I already tied these and they work. I tried multiple types of answers such as roots that are negative, or both positive, or one of each. :P

Comment: @Mirko But the solutions of those _don't_ have a difference of $1$. They're inconsistent.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I've tried over hundreds of roots, and they all worked. :P

Comment: Here's a problem: Solve the _cubic_! $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$. Warning: The solution is very complicated, was only discovered several centuries ago (while that of the quadratic was discovered millennia ago), and may involve complex numbers even if all three roots are real.

Comment: @babyguineapig11 I was referring to Mirko's specific examples.

Comment: this doesn't feel like solving an equation. It feels like having the solutions and then cooking up an equation that satisfies them.

Comment: @Mirko That is kinda the whole way math works, though. Multiplying Binomials is reversed by factoring quadratics, and everything in math has a reverse action. Technically, you can find the solution of a 2*2 by taking 4/2. It may seem like I'm just making equations by using the solutions.